# How to load jqGrid on the modal dialog jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am calling the function `GetGrid_Data()` to load the jqGrid...But no luck.
Is this the way one loads content on the modal dialog if not please suggest the way..Thanks in advance.

```
function ClickFirstName() {
   $('.GetLink').click(function () {
      $('#dialog-box').dialog({
         title: "Ageing details",
         modal: true,
         draggable: false,
         width: '50%',
         height: 500,
         open: function(){
         GetGrid_Data();
         },   
         buttons: {
         "Close": function () {
         $(this).dialog("close");
         }
        }
       });
      });
         //Get_Dialog();
    }
    function GetGrid_Data() {
                alert("Hello");
                $('#grid2').jqGrid({
                    data: pateintsData,
                    datatype: 'local',
                    colNames: ['Speciality', 'LIP', 'Days', 'PLA'],
                    colModel: [
                { name: 'Speciality', index: 'Speciality', width: 200, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'LIP', index: 'LIP', align: 'center', width: 200, editable: true },
                { name: 'Days', index: 'Days', align: 'center', width: 200, editable: true },
                    { name: 'PLA', index: 'PLA', align: 'center', width: 300, editable: true }
                    ],
                        //onSortCol: function (name, index) { alert("Column Name: " + name + " Column Index: " + index); },
                        sortname: 'Speciality',
                        editurl: "clientArray",
                        sortorder: 'asc',
                        scrollOffset: 0,
                        gridview: true,
                        hidegrid: false,
                        height: 680,
                        shrinkToFit: true,
                        altRows: true,
                        altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
                        viewrecords: true
                   });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is `<table id="grid2"></table>` inside of the div with id="dialog-box" (the dialog)? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which version of jQuery UI you use? It's better if you create the demo (in jsfiddle for example), which reproduces the problem.

Comment: `'#grid2'` should be inside the modal dialog html.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the reply....I am using jqGrid version 4.5.2 and the #grid2 is inside "dialog" the div for modal dialog...I am using jquery 1.2.1 version...
Is there any other option other than open where i can include the jqGrid code

Comment: @Deb Thanks for the reply...Yes the grid2 is inside div element "dialog"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you have to append the dialog to html body. Try doing the following:

`$('.GetLink').click(function () {
    var $div = $('<div id="dialog-box"> +
        '<div id="grid2Div">' +
        '<table id="grid2"></table>' +
        '<div id="grid2"></div></div></div>';
    $('body').append($div);
    $('#dialog-box').dialog({`

Let us know if it works. Cheers!